# Python exercise with sine function in a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I came upon this exercise some time ago and could never solve it as the question tells me to. Here it is:

1. Write a function called `print_sine_wave(m,n)` that plots half a sine function using only asterisks on a matrix that has n lines and m columnn. For example, `print_sine_wave(17,11)` results in

   ```
    *          
         *
             *
                *
                   *
                    * 
                   *
                *
             *
         *
    *
   ```

I've tried different approaches but none would plot exactly as this result (with spaces and asterisks). I'm using Python 2.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you *think* should work and we can suggest why it doesn't.  Incidentally, this should be no more than three or four lines of code.

Comment: Show whatever approach you think came closest, and where you got stuck on making it work. Otherwise, you're just asking us to write your code for you, and SO isn't good for that.

Comment: As a hint: You can multiply sequences by integers, so `' ' * (n-1) + '*'` gives you n-1 spaces followed by 1 asterisk. So now you only need to figure out how to generate the right `n` for each line (and multiply it by the width and round to an integer, of course).

Comment: I didn't post it because that was from a test I had in college some years ago, so I couldn't save the code for myself but seeing the question again in my old files drove me curious. As of now, I'm really not good in Python anymore and there's nothing I would accomplish on studying again only to solve this. At the time I knew the answer was something simple that I probably missed when studying. Anyways, I'll try abarnert's approach and see what I can do. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from math import sin, pi

def print_sine_wave(lines, columns):
    for pos_x in range(lines+1):
        x = float(pos_x - float(lines) / 2) / (float(lines) / 2) + .5
        pos_y = int(sin(x * pi) * columns + .5) + columns
        print ('%4.1f' % x) + ' ' * pos_y + '*'


print_sine_wave(20, 30)
```

resulting in:

```
-0.5 *
-0.4  *
-0.3       *
-0.2             *
-0.1                      *
 0.0                              *
 0.1                                       *
 0.2                                                *
 0.3                                                      *
 0.4                                                           *
 0.5                                                            *
 0.6                                                           *
 0.7                                                      *
 0.8                                                *
 0.9                                       *
 1.0                              *
 1.1                      *
 1.2             *
 1.3       *
 1.4  *
 1.5 *
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be white-space differences caused by different rounding. Consider:

1. The interval of your function. To get a perfect curve, the first line needs to represent sin(0) and the last line needs to represent sin(1). It's a very easy mistake to write (using my example) `sin(pi * j / n)` which means `j` never quite gets to `i` leaving your last line just short of reaching pi.
2. The amplitude of your function. I've rounded down by calling `int` on a `float`. It would be entirely valid to use the built-in [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function (or `math.floor`). `round` will return a floating point number still which will need to be converted to an `int` anyway.

Here's my example that covers the interval 0 to pi (giving a half wavelength):

```
from math import sin, pi

def print_sine_wave(m, n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(' ' * int(m * sin(pi * j / (n - 1))) + '*')

print_sine_wave(17, 11)
```

resulting in:

```
*
     *
         *
             *
                *
                 *
                *
             *
         *
     *
*
```